is it possible to tame the numerical instability of this recurrence relation?
I need to compute an array of values using a multidimensional recurrence relation, but it exhibits numerical instabilities. The recurrence relation is parametrized by a $N$-dim complex vector $b$ and a complex symmetric NxN matrix $M$ with eigenvalues in the complex unit disk. Here is the $N=2$ case:
$$
\begin{cases}
F_{0,0} = const\\
F_{m+1,n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{m+1}}\biggl[b_0 F_{mn} + M_{00} \sqrt{m} F_{m-1,n} + M_{01} \sqrt{n} F_{m,n-1} \biggr]\\
F_{m,n+1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\,\biggl[b_1 F_{mn} + M_{10} \sqrt{m} F_{m-1,n} + M_{11} \sqrt{n} F_{m,n-1} \biggr]\\
\end{cases}
$$
For large enough values of $m$ and $n$ the values of $F$ blow up.
Here is a simple python implementation if you want to try it. The case $M = \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$, $b=(z, -z^*)$ and $const=\exp(-|z|^2)$ is mathematically guaranteed that $|F_{mn}|<1$ but numerically it's not the case (e.g. try z=5 and already at $m=n=70$ things break down.
import numpy as np

def computeF(max_m: int, max_n: int, const, b, M):
    F = np.zeros((max_m, max_n), dtype=np.complex128)

    F[0,0] = const

    for n in range(max_n-1):
        for m in range(max_m-1):
        
            # go down n-th column
            F[m+1,n] = (b[0]*F[m,n] + M[0,0]*np.sqrt(m)*F[m-1,n] + M[0,1]*np.sqrt(n)*F[m,n-1]) / np.sqrt(m+1)
        
        # 1st element of next column
        F[0,n+1] = (b[1]*F[0,n] + M[1,1]*np.sqrt(n)*F[0,n-1]) / np.sqrt(n+1)
    return F

What techniques can I throw at this issue other than cranking up the numerical precision? (which I can do, but it becomes way too slow and anyways eventually fails too).
I've tried looking into a backward version of the recurrence relation, but this works only for 1D where I can start with any guess and then adjust at the end (I'd need $N$+1 guesses for the $N$-dim version). I've also tried redefining the relation for $G_{mn}=F_{mn} / \sqrt{m!n!}$, but it does't help either.
EDIT: From @salcio's comment I can see that perhaps there's no chance to fully stabilize it, in which case I'm still interested in delaying the numerical instabilities, even if I can't get rid of them for all $m,n$

Write the relation in the matrix form, then reduce the matrix to Jordan's form. If an eigenvalue is larger than $1$ in absolute value than no much chance to "stabilize it".

By matrix form you mean to write the vector $(F_{m+1,n}, F_{m,n+1})$ as the solution of a linear system?

I ask because I can see two ways to write it in matrix form:

$({+1,}, {,+1}) =$ [some 2x3 matrix] $(F{m-1,n}, F{m,n}, F_{m,n-1})$
or using a 5x5 matrix acting on the vector $(F_{m-1,n}, F_{m,n}, F_{m,n-1}, F_{m+1,n}, F_{m,n+1})$


I don't understand how you'd compute $F_{0,1}$, for the second recurrence would refer to $F_{-1,0}$.

Good observation. At the edges the contributions that would come from "outside" count as zeros because whatever value you want to give $F_{-1,0}$ it will be multiplied by $\sqrt{0}$. Does that answer your question?

@Salcio would you have a reference that I can look into as a follow-up on your comment about eigenvalues?
